# Sourcing a script in R in a custom environment => Loading packages does not work

Tags: r, namespaces, package

I have a package for mortality tables and I also want to provide several dozens of example life tables, which should not be loaded by default, but only on request (because they are potentially large objects). I don't want to litter the global namespace, so I'm trying to create my own namespace (attach'ed to the search path) and then later on-demand source a script to create the desired life table object(s). In the source command, I provide my own environment, so the tables end up there rather than in the global namespace.

This works quite will, with the only exception that all packages that are loaded in the sourced script are NOT available in the script.

Simple, minimal example:

```r
# Create my own enviroment in the search path; Later on, we'll add objects by sourcing a script
myenv = attach(list(), name = "myTestEnv")

# I have a script that loads required packages and creates some new variables, which should be stored in my custom environment (so it does not pollute the global namespace):
writeLines("require(tidyr); a = 1; df = gather(data.frame(a=1:5))", "myTest.R")
```

However, when sourcing to a given environment, all packages loaded in that
script are NOT available:

```r
source("myTest.R", local = myenv)
```

> Fehler in gather(data.frame(a = 1:5)) :
> konnte Funktion "gather" nicht finden

a is correctly added (before the error occurred), so adding to the namespace works, it's just that the packages loaded in the script are not available.

```r
ls.str(envir = myenv)
```

> a :  num 1

Sourcing into the global namespace works fine and the package is available in the sourced
file:

```r
source("myTest.R")
ls.str(envir = globalenv())
```

```
a :  num 1
df : 'data.frame':  5 obs. of  2 variables:
   $ key  : chr  "a" "a" "a" "a" ...
   $ value: int  1 2 3 4 5
```

How can I load packages in a sourced file that uses its own environment for evaluation?

Comment: I think what you are describing (load expensive package data only when needed) is exactly what `LazyData:` is meant to do. Look for "lazydata" in https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html, and I suggest you read https://r-pkgs.org/data.html.

Comment: Lazy data sounds like a good idea for large data sets, which can be provided by a single package. In my case, I really need to run some code, as some of the mortality tables are created on the fly by downloading current data from the Human Mortality Database etc. Other tables load a table from a user-provided Excel file (which must not be changed / included in a package due to license issues).

Comment: Both of those tasks sound like straight-forward functions: `get_onthefly_table()` and `import_userprovided_exceltable("path/to/quux.xlsx")`. Is there a reason you need to deal with `source`ing R files vice defining functions within the package?

Comment: For now, I'm using the approach described in r-pkgs.org/data.html about "Raw data", where I also provide a loader .R script, which I'm trying to source.